# How to vertically centre elements in a ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a number of Switch elements laid out in a `ListView`. Currently they're appearing as follows:

[image]

but I need them to be vertically centred, e.g.

[image]

I'm using the following AXML as the definition for each list item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget32"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switchOutput"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="[Output Name]"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgTime"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/datetime"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I thought `android:gravity="center_vertical"` would be enough to get them to appear correctly, but it doesn't appear to be working. What do I need to get the switches vertically centred in each list item?

Comment: add `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` will center that child vertically within its parent

Comment: This worked. Why don't you add it as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`... This will center that child vertically within its parent...

[layout_centerVertical](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_centerVertical)

**Note:-** parent layout must be `RelativeLayout`..

**OP Edit:** this is the correctly centred layout now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget32"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switchOutput"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="[Output Name]"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgTime"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/datetime"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the `center` tag to the Parent `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/widget32"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switchOutput"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgTime"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="[Output Name]" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imgTime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/datetime" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
android: layout_centerVertical = "true".
```